# Keras layer weights shape is different compared to other conventions

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have been looking at the `layers.weights` output of Keras layers. The shape of the layer weight matrix is listed as `(number_of_inputfeatures, dense_layer_neurons)`.

The [first example](https://keras.io/api/layers/) in docs.

However, all the theoretical courses I saw, as well as in pytorch, layers have weight matrix shape the opposite way where weight matrix shape is given by `(dense_layer_neurons,  input_features)` or `(layer_2_neurons, layer_1_neurons)`

https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/getting-your-matrix-dimensions-right-Rz47X

Why are these two conventions opposite to each other?

Am I missing anything? Can someone please clarify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Explains it - weight matrix shape is dependent on how you shape the input data

https://medium.com/from-the-scratch/deep-learning-deep-guide-for-all-your-matrix-dimensions-and-calculations-415012de1568